# Big oh property

Tags: soft-question

Suppose that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two non negative functions and suppose that $$f(x)=O(g(x)).$$
Can we conclude that $$-g(x)=O(-f(x)) ?$$ I think is false but i'm not sure. Thank you and sorry for this dumb question.

Comment: No: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition

Comment: Remember that $O(\cdot)$ is only concerned with the *absolute value* of the functions involved.  Have you tried any examples?

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
|f(x)| & \le C |g(x)| \\
\Rightarrow -C |g(x)| & \le -|f(x)| \\
\not\Rightarrow |g(x)| & \le C^{-1} |f(x)|
\end{align*}$$
So the answer is no, since $\mathcal O$ refers to the *absolut value* of a function.

Comment: The $\geq$ in the second line should be $\leq$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thank you :) I forgot the sign change from swapping the sides^^

Answer (score 0):

Even with the right signs this is false. For example, for $x>1$, we have that $1=O(x)$, but $x\neq O(1)$.